# Android library and Unity plugin communication issues. Cannot reference enum type and pass back button event to android

Tags: android, plugins, enums, unity-game-engine

I am quite new at Unity and I am trying to create a Unity plugin for an Android library and I ma facing the following issues:

1) I can't find a way to pass the back button event to Android library. What I have managed to do is to pass touch events to the activity on the Android side by setting the following line

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDal vik" android:value="true" />
```

at `<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" ... >` in the `AndroidManifest`

However I cannot pass the back button event in a way that I do not have to change the code in the library

What I do for now in my script is

```
public void Update() {

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
Application.Quit();
}
```

However I need the option to pass that back event that I capture, to the library and not handle it at the Unity layer.

2) I am trying to reference in my script an enum that I have in my Android library.

For example I have the following enum in a `Place.java` file

```
package com.myapp.constants;

public enum Place { TOP, BOTTOM, RIGHT, LEFT }
```

and I want to find a way to reference it from my script.

I tried something like that:

```
AndroidJavaClass topPlace = new AndroidJavaClass("com.myapp.constants.TOP");
```

but with no luck.

Can anyone help on those issues? Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

2) An enum in Java is a regular class, and its enumeration values are instances of that class, stored in static fields. So to get them, you'd do this:

```
AndroidJavaObject topValue = new AndroidJavaClass("com.myapp.constants.Place").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("TOP");
```

Comment: Vladimir thank you for your answer. Do you know the solution to 1) part of the question too?

Comment: I'm not knowledgable enough in Android to say. Worst case scenario, just have a direct call to the Java plugin. If you're writing it, why not?

Comment: What do you mean direct call to the Java plugin? I capture the event in the Unity layer? How to pass it to the Java library layer?

Comment: If you're writing the plugin, then you can get your own Java classes with AndroidJavaClass/Object, and call methods on them, just like with the enum above. But you knew this already - so I'm thinking there's a different problem here I don't understand.

Comment: the weird thing here is that Unity layer prevents events like the back key event in Android to pass to the Java layer..